# I am working with the flutter and my build gradle showing error

Tags: android, flutter

this is the error message showing on the build.gradle file of the android folder:

[image: Supplied javaHome is not a valid folder. You supplied: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20Java(0)]

showing this error
I have tried to start a new project, but the same issue is showing.

Can anyone please solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was project JDK location. From the Android Studio Project tool window, right clicked on the root directory, selected 'module settings', and set the JDK location. Everything's fine now.

or

I tried this and it worked for me flawlessly. go To SETTING-->SEARCH 'Gradle'---> and choose Gradle JVM and choose the option Use JAVA_HOME C:\ProgramFiles\Java\JDK\1.8 hope this helps someone.